# How can I move text to the top of an absolute text box? (CSS)

Tags: css, text, alignment

I don't see why the text starts in the middle anyway. I can use vertical-align to center it, but not move it up. I can't alter the padding, either. How can I move the text to the top? I'm trying to make a simple text box.

My HTML:

```
    <label for="checkbox" id="rant" />RANT</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
    <input type="text" id="rantbox" />
```

My CSS:

```
#rantbox {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    }
#checkbox:checked + #rantbox {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px; 
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    font-size: 15px;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 150px;
    text-align: top;
    vertical-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: What div? You talk about a div, but there is no div in your code.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you. The whole thing is wrapped in a body div, but I mean the text box. How do I get the text to start at the top of the text box?

Comment: You are using input type text (with extreme large height), but, in this case, more appropriate element would be textarea, i think? https://jsfiddle.net/09r8yax1/

Comment: Hi, there is a trick that you could use a span with absolute position into your input and after input is checking span position could be changed by css